# Beginning PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Currently I started Developing PhoneGap Application in Eclipse IDE.
The problem is how can I migrate this project and support it for ios, windows..etc and are there any tools to convert the project source code? And also I could not understand how phonegap build works i.e Case:

1. Can I code the phonegap application in eclipse IDE and after completing and uploading the files in phonebuild does it take care of building .apk or .ipa etc?
2. Should we have to only upload the html, css and javascript files in zip format and does the phonegapbuild takecare of building .apk, .ipa files?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain in brief the deployment process after building the phonegap app in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an app for multiple platform, the only thing you should edit in an IDE are html/js/css files.

For all the rest, you should be using the cordova CLI.

If you need some native stuffs, use plugins that exist for all the platforms you target, and if no plugin exist for what you want to do, build your own plugin, but in that case you will have to write native code for each platform.

You don't need Eclipse at all to build the project.

### Edit to add little more explanations

About the CLI, I suggest you read cordova documentation or read a tutorial like http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/

Basicaly,

1. You install cordova cli using npm
2. you install any sdk you may need (knowing that ios sdk can be installed only on OSX and windows phone sdk needs Windows 8) and configure the enfironement as described in the cordova platform
3. you create your project using the `cordova create ...` command line (adding parameters to set your app name...
4. you change html, js... in the www folder using a text editor or any ide you like
5. you add all needed plugins you may need using the `cordova plugin add ...`
6. for each platform you want to target, you add the platform using the `cordova platform add ...` command

Then you can use `cordova run ...` or `cordova build ...` to run/build for a platform.

Comment: But can you please explain briefly like how exactly to develop a phonegap application and how to test the application..and how exactly cordova CLI works like?